# FineTune TSQL SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The below query takes a lot of time, like 80 minutes to return 1400 results, any recommendation how to tune this

```
exec sp_executesql N'set ARITHIGNORE ON;
SELECT TOP (@solutionid) 
        b.[solutionid],MAX(b.title) title,
        MIN(a.[Status]) [Status],
        MIN(a.[Audience]) Audience,
        MAX(b.productname) ProductName, 
        MIN(CAST( DateCreated as datetime)) DateCreated ,
        MIN(CAST( DateLastModified as datetime)) DateModified,
        [pc_pres_text]=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT [pc_pres_text] as [data()]
FROM    [dbo.view] a
WHERE   a.[solutionid]=b.[solutionid]
FOR XML PATH('''')), ''&lt;'',''<''),''&gt;'',''>'') ,''&amp;'',''&''), 
        ''http://support/supp=''+b.[solutionid] PrimusUrl
FROM    [view] b
INNER JOIN [table] a ON b.solutionid=a.solutionid
WHERE   ((@Audience IS NULL AND [Audience] IS NULL) OR [Audience] LIKE @Audience) AND [DateCreated] > @DateCreated AND 
        ((@Status IS NULL AND [Status] IS NULL) OR [Status] = @Status)
GROUP BY b.[solutionid]
ORDER BY b.[solutionid]',N'@Audience nvarchar(10),@DateCreated datetime,@Status nvarchar(9),@solutionid bigint',
@Audience=N'test%',@DateCreated='2000-01-01 00:00:00',@Status=N'test',@solutionid=500000
```

Comment: Could you please add your tables structure and eventually existing indexes?

Comment: Another thing to add would be the amount of data that's actually being dealt with. Are we talking thousands of records or millions?  Finally have you run any sort of query tuning tools against the query?

Comment: Is solutionid indexed? How many rows are in dbo.view?

Comment: As a side note, I've seen SQL server absolutely choke on XML data that passes the 64k boundary.  In one case I saw a query which returned 60K of xml data in 3 seconds; the same query when run that returned 4k more of data took 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the problem is I only have read access and view has around 50000 rows. Also solution id is not indexed.

Comment: Solution ID is nvarchar, is it ok to add index to varchar ?

Comment: @Nick - What version of SQL Server are you on? There are quite a few possible problems with this query (possible missing indexes, dynamic search conditions without `recompile` hint, maybe something sub optimal in the `XML PATH` placement in the plan - is it doing it before the `group by`?) please post the actual execution plan so we can see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing parameter for @audience and @status then no need to test for a null condition but that is not going to do much to performance.  If you do not output to XML do you still have performance problem?  Include hint with (nolock) or possibly (holdlock). Not sure you can (holdlock) on a view - you might need to break it down to the tables for (holdlock).  Why the cast on DateCreated and DateLastModified - are they text fields in SQL?   If they are text and will cast to datetime then why not store them as datetime?

Answer (score 0):

First, BalamBalam recommends using nolock.  This can indeed help performance enormously when used properly, but it can cause dirty reads and lead to inconsistent results.  In short, nolock can be useful but it should be used with great caution and full understanding of the risks it involves.

Next, I would definitely take a look at your indexes.  The missing index feature can give you a good idea of what specifically to look at, but offhand I would certainly make sure all solutionId columns are indexed.

Finally, this has some general performance thoughts that may be useful as you optimize this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance/71001/

Comment: I TOTALLY agree that nolock is not to be taken lightly.  But a query that runs 80 minutes and returns 1400 results is a candidate.  The data is 80 minutes stale anyway.  In general if you do need to hold a lock then should limit the scope of query to only the data chunk you need "clean".  On the other extreme I doubt holdlock is the right answer for this situation but something to consider.

Comment: Yes, I think this may be a candidate for nolock, but anyone using nolock needs to understand that risks that come with it.